# How to run Adaptive TPE in hyperopt?

Tags: python, hyperopt

I read [documentation of Hyperopt](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/) in python, and I found, that there are three possible methods:

1. RandomSearch
2. TPE
3. Adaptive TPE

To run random search we have command `rand.suggest`, and TPE `tpe.suggest`, however, I couldn't nowhere find any command which tells me how can I run adaptive TPE. Could you please tell me how it can be ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't explained in the documentation, but by looking around in the GitHub issues I found that the Adaptive TPE implementation is where one might expect:

```py
from hyperopt import hp, fmin, atpe  # <-----

# define the search space

best = fmin(objective, space, algo=atpe.suggest, max_evals=100)
```